# How to cite a multi-volume book of collected works with BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, custom-bib

I would like to cite a particular volume within a multi-volume book
that is the collected works of some author.

The collected works were edited by an editor. 
I am using a custom `.bst` file that I created via

```
latex makebst
```

What would be the correct BibTeX entry? 
Note that I am forced to use BibTeX only and unfortunately cannot resort to `biblatex` or the like.

Comment: A typical entry:
@BOOK{author,
        author = {Author},
        title = {Title},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        year = {Year}
}
In my case there would be another entry "editor".
I am not bound to a specific .bst file. 
If there are any standard .bst files that allow me to cite a multivolume
book, that's fine with me.
But I don't want to fiddle with internal stuff at this point.
Of course, I could further customize my .bst file by writing a function

    FUNCTION {multivolumebook}
    {
      ...
    }

but I am simply wondering, if there are is a standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 3):

Consider to use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex). Here's how an entry of your desired type looks like with `biblatex` (taken from `biblatex-examples.bib`):

```
@book{coleridge,
  hyphenation = {british},
  author = {Coleridge, Samuel Taylor},
  editor = {Coburn, Kathleen and Engell, James and Bate, W. Jackson},
  indextitle = {Biographia literaria},
  title = {Biographia literaria, or Biographical sketches of my literary life
    and opinions},
  shorttitle = {Biographia literaria},
  maintitle = {The collected works of Samuel Taylor Coleridge},
  part = {2},
  volume = {7},
  series = {Bollingen Series},
  number = {75},
  publisher = {Routledge and Kegan Paul},
  location = {London},
  date = {1983},
  annotation = {One (partial) volume of a multivolume book. This is a
    \texttt{book} entry with a \texttt{volume} and a \texttt{part} field
    which explicitly refers to the second (physical) part of the seventh
    (logical) volume. Also note the \texttt{series} and \texttt{number}
    fields}
}
```

Compilable example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{coleridge}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, I am forced to use BibTeX in this case.

Comment: @Aton In that case, edit your question accordingly and also state which `.bst` style you're currently using. Perhaps someone can suggest a suitable non-`biblatex` solution then.

Comment: The question explicitly mentions BibTeX.

Comment: @Aton `biblatex` can also be used with BibTeX (the program) and uses `.bib` files, so it wasn't clear to me if `biblatex` was a no-go in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I added a corresponding remark.